# jquery full calendar not showing events on ipad safari browser

Tags: php, jquery, ipad, fullcalendar

I am working on [jQuery full calendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) and its showing events on windows/Linux and if i am testing on iPad(safari browser), calendar is not showing events. If i click on any date, event click function is working properly but not showing events at all.

Here is my code :

```
var SITE_URL = 'MY_SITE_URL';

$(document).ready(function () {
    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();
    var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,basicWeek'
            },
            editable: true,
            draggable: true,
            dayClick: function (date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
                var myDate = new Date();

                if (date.getDate() < myDate.getDate()) {
                    //TRUE Clicked date smaller than today
                    alert("You cannot book on this day!");
                } else {
                    //dynamically load soloads which are not assigned to any date
                    var mmon = parseInt(date.getMonth() + 1);
                    var clicked_date = date.getDate() + '_' + mmon + '_' + date.getFullYear();
                    $('#get_selected_date').val(clicked_date);
                    $.ajax({
                        url: SITE_URL + 'member/getUserUnassignedAds',
                        type: 'POST',
                        success: function (data) {
                            $('#soloadsdropdown').html(data);
                            $('#addsoloadformlink').trigger('click');
                        }
                    });
                }
            },
            events: function (start, end, callback) {
                // on calendar loads this ajax runs
                $.ajax({
                    url: SITE_URL + 'member/getUserAllAssignedAds',
                    success: function (doc) {
                        var doc = $.parseJSON(doc);

                        var events = [];
                        $(doc).each(function (i, val) {
                            events.push({
                                id: doc[i].id,
                                title: doc[i].title,
                                start: new Date(doc[i].start),
                                color: doc[i].color
                            });
                        });
                        callback(events);
                    }
                });
            },
            eventDrop: function (event, dayDelta, minuteDelta, allDay, revertFunc) {
                var dataString = 'assign_id=' + event.id;
                $.ajax({
                    url: SITE_URL + 'member/checkIfAdIsOrdered',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: dataString,
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data != '0') {
                            if (data == 'mybought') {
                                alert("You cannot schedule bought ads!");
                            } else {
                                alert("You cannot rearrange sold ads!");
                            }
                            revertFunc();
                        } else {
                            if (!confirm("Do you really want to reschedule " + event.title + "?")) {
                                revertFunc();
                            } else {
                                var dataString = 'move_days=' + dayDelta + '&assign_id=' + event.id;
                                $.ajax({
                                    url: SITE_URL + 'member/updateUserActiveAssignedAds',
                                    type: 'POST',
                                    data: dataString,
                                    success: function (data) {
                                        if (data == 'pastdate') {
                                            alert("You cannot edit past date events!");
                                            revertFunc();
                                        } else if (data == 'notdone') {
                                            alert("You cannot book on this day!");
                                            revertFunc();
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            },
            eventClick: function (event) {
                var dataString = 'assign_id=' + event.id;
                $.ajax({
                    url: SITE_URL + 'member/checkIfAdIsOrdered',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: dataString,
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data == 'pastdate') {
                            alert("You cannot edit past date events!");
                        } else if (data == 'reservedad') {
                            $('#clickreservebox').trigger('click');
                            $('#reservebox').show();
                            $('#unreservethisad').attr('rel', event.id);
                        } else {
                            if (data != '0' || data == 'mybought') {
                                $('#myOrderModal').html(data);
                                $('#clickorderconfirmbox').trigger('click');
                                $('#redirectbox').show();
                            } else {
                                $('#clickconfirmbox').trigger('click');
                                $('#confirmbox').show();
                                $('.pp-reserve-btn').attr('rel', event.id);
                                $('.pp-close-ii').attr('rel', event.id);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
    });
});

//At the end to make it real time i have added
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function(){ 
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Are you here for a good time, or a long time?

Comment: @Fred what do you mean by this?? If you have the answer please give me the solution.

Comment: I see so many new members come on and ask questions, that don't bother replying after spending much time and energy, which at this time of night, I do not have much left of either. Welcome to SO by the way.

Comment: Actually its day time my side. Thank you and please resolve my problem.

Comment: It's 2:30 am here. I'll have a quick look at it but I can't make any promises.

Comment: You're welcome. I Google'd your problem but did not find anything related to the script you're using, sorry. Cheers

Comment: @ArunSrivastava I guess there's a variation in handling the events between Desktop & mobile platforms.. right ? How about using jQuery mobile ?

Comment: I have used it earlier but can't find any solution.

Comment: here is my code @Avinash  `$iphone  = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], "iPhone");
  $android = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], "Android");
  $palmpre = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], "webOS");
  $berry   = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], "BlackBerry");
  $ipod    = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], "iPod");
  $ipad    = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], "iPad");
  $windows = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], "Zune");
  if ($iphone || $android || $palmpre || $ipod || $ipad || $windows || $berry == true)
  {// mobile jquery and css}`

Comment: I am also having the same problem.

Comment: I have a similar issue

Answer (score 0):

By saying it's not populating, you mean no events are loaded right? Had a similar issue, and it was because the path to the backend is CASE SENSITIVE on MAC instead of windows. So check your SITE_URL variable maybe once more if its right.

also while on mac u could use Safari to inspect possible errors on the device.
[Take a look here](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/workflow-tutorials/quick-tip-using-web-inspector-to-debug-mobile-safari/) for a tutorial